# Why can a class be used within itself in member function definition, but is regarded as incomplete when used as a member?

Tags: c++, types

```
class A
{
     private:
        A a;
};
```

Why is the A in class an incomplete type?

```
class A
{
     public:
          A& operator= (A a){return *this;}
};
```

Is not the parameter `A` of `operator=` an incomplete type? Why does the code above compile?

Comment: A type is incomplete until the closing brace `};` of its definition.

Comment: @KerrekSB That doesn't answer the question. In the second case we are also before the closing brace of `A`'s definition.

Comment: The basic problem here is that I'd like you to think about is how big is `A`? How much memory should the compiler reserve for it? Is it infinite?

Comment: This question's title is terrible. Please improve it.

Comment: @BartoszKP: Well, there is no "the question" here, because the OP asked a bunch of questions all at once. Function parameter types may be incomplete; so there's a whole separate misunderstanding going in on the second part.

Answer (score 4):

Because there is a difference between using `A` in open space in the class definition, and using it in the parameter-list of a member function definition. Those are two different scopes.

> `[C++11: 9.2/2]:` A class is considered a completely-defined object type (3.9) (or complete type) at the closing `}` of the *class-specifier*. Within the class *member-specification*, the class is regarded as complete within function bodies, default arguments, exception-specifications, and *brace-or-equal-initializers* for non-static data members (including such things in nested classes). **Otherwise it is regarded as incomplete within its own class *member-specification*.**

And then the following special case:

> `[C++11: 8.3.5/9]`: Types shall not be defined in return or parameter types. **The type of a parameter** or the return type **for a function definition shall not be an incomplete class type** (possibly cv-qualified) **unless the function definition is nested within the *member-specification* for that class** (including definitions in nested classes defined within the class).

"That's just the way it is."

Speaking practically, it's clear that it would be impossible to store an `A` within an `A` (because that would require infinite encapsulation), whereas this is obviously not the case in a member function's parameter list. So the standard committee had the opportunity to make this a little easier for us, and they took it.

Furthermore, if you were to try to use a member of `a` inside the function's *definition*, then that is also allowed (per the first quote above), as if the function had been declared lexically after the end of the class definition.

Comment: +1 In n4296 The second statement has been moved from 8.3.5/9 to 8.3.5/11 and it omits the "unless the function definition is ...". Any idea why?

Comment: @imreal: I think the key is the replacement suffix _"in the context of the function definition"_, which appears to refer to the function definition body (triggering 9.2/2 per above) despite seeming somewhat ambiguous as far as I can tell. The prose from the proposal that led to this wording ([CWG #1824](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1824)) supports my assessment, though I think the resulting wording is not quite up to scratch.

Answer (score 1):

The first block is an impossibility in the general case, as to know what `sizeof(A)` (for the class) is it needs to know what `sizeof(A)` is (for the member).

The second case is different in that even if the definition of the member function is syntactically *inside* the class, the language considers the definition to be *outside* of the class.  The compiler will translate that code as if you had typed it like:

```
class A {
public:
   A& operator=(A a);
};
inline A& A::operator=(A a) { return *this; }
```

Declaring a function taking or returning an object of incomplete type is legal.  When the type is really used, inside the function definition outside of the class, the type is already complete, so it is perfectly fine too.

Comment: That rationale doesn't solve the problem — you still have `A` named in the declaration.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Uhm... *Declaring a function taking or returning an object of incomplete type is legal.*, is that not clear?

Comment: Fair enough. However: _"the language considers the definition to be outside of the class"_ Not really; they are implicitly `inline` in this case but not if you lexically define them outside of the class definition.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yeah, right... missed the `inline` in the transformed version. But the behavior required by the standard is that. The language is processed top-down, but in a member function definition you can refer to members that have not yet been declared inside the class, the compiler is forced into doing the equivalent to the transformation I mentioned, legalese aside.

Answer (score 0):

The way to look at this would be to understand what would happen if this was actually legal. When a class is instantiated, all its class members are constructed first. So, in your example, the construction of `A a` will take place before A is fully constructed, which is not possible.

Also, this will result in an infinite recursive construction of objects of A.

Answer (score -1):

Second one is compiling because you are using only A's reference not an object of A. Reference doesn't need complete type. But in first case you need A's object and hence complete type will be required, which can only happen after closing }

Comment: It's not A's reference in the parameter list.

Comment: There are no references here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit There is one - the return type of `operator=` and this is what nkvns probably is referring to :)